# Using the OTP and RSA compared to only using the OTP itself

Tags: encryption, rsa, one-time-pad

To use the OTP with RSA, I implemented the one-time pad first for only one time, and then I used the RSA algorithm to encrypt the message.

For the RSA algorithm, I pick $p$ = 2143 and $q$ = 3257, values which do not share any common factors and generate a random value between 1 and $(p-1)(q-1)$. Then generate a public key and private key for RSA encryption and decryption.

My question is: Is it more secure than only using the one-time pad to encrypt the message?

Comment: OTP, done right, is 100% secure; how can you have more than 100%?

Comment: Could you please expand on how you use RSA?  When and how do you manage the key(s)?  A bit more detail should lead to a more accurate answer.

Comment: @dandavis : ​ For example, one could have non-[malleability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: So you create cipher text using a OTP, then you encrypt the cipher text again with RSA?  So you have two layers of encryption.  The question then becomes generically are multiple layers of encryption more secure than a single layer?  That's a good question and I don't think that the answer is simple.

Comment: @dandavis I think that is a very simplistic and incorrect view.  The security of a crypto SYSTEM depends on much much more than the underlying mathematics (which comparatively are simple).

Comment: @PaulUszak: I agree it depends on more than what we know from OP, but i said "done right"...

Comment: This is actually the sneakiest part of your question; how did you generate the OTP?

Comment: RSA with small parameters as in the question is extremely insecure. $p$ ans $q$ need to have in the order of a thousand bits at least, not twelve! The OTP is secure if the pad is uniformly random, used once only, and transmitted securely to the recipient, each of which are hard, and why the OTP is seldom used in practice.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you would use the RSA algorithm for since a [one-time pad](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/One-time_pad) (assuming you implement it correctly) should achieve perfect secrecy, which means its ciphertext cannot be cracked. [RSA](https://www.quora.com/Where-is-RSA-encryption-used) is one of the first public-key cryptosystems that can also be considered as secure when you are using large enough primes.

So to answer your question, it cannot be more secure than using OTP only since it simply provides the perfect secrecy. But OTP does have its [limitations](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/one-time-pad-why-is-it-useless-in-practice) and that's why we have other encryption schemes and algorithms so that we can choose the most suitable one in different situations.